# <img> and center aligned <span> in the same line doesn't work

Tags: html

I'm new to coding and basically don't understand anything and I've been trying to solve this problem for about a week and haven't got anywhere close

here is my HTML code

```css
.cats {
  height: 118px;
  width: auto;
  object-position: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="cats" src="black.jpeg" alt="beautiful cat">
  <span style="text-align: center;">cutie</span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to have the image at the left like it is by default and have my text in the same line aligned to the center of the page.

Comment: span not center you can use 'p' or 'div' tag with display: inline-block and text-align: center

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: just add ```display: flex``` to the div.

Comment: @HasipTimurtas That won't solve the OPs problem with `display: flex` alone. The key is the `margin: 0 auto` to make the left/right margins auto between the text and the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your looking for? For the `<img>` to be positioned at the top left of the viewport and the `<span>` text to be centered on the page. Try this out.

```css
.cats {
    height: 118px;
    width: auto;
    object-position: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container span {
  /* width: 85%; vary width to your liking if need be */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="cats" src="https://i.ibb.co/56tbCQP/Screen-Shot-2021-02-25-at-8-46-16-PM.png" alt="beautiful cat">
    <span style="text-align: center;">cutie</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `margin: 0 auto;` looks more centered.

Comment: @KarthikNayak98 Yeah that's what I originally thought too. I edited my answer to comment out the `width: 85%` to let the OP decide what they need. At larger viewports, the left/right auto margin makes it a "bit" off center due to the size of the `<img>` but at smaller screens it looks perfectly centered without any width tinkering.

Comment: woaw! It finally works!!! Could I pm you so i could understand this code more because I don't really know what's going on and also to make it the center of the container not affected by the image, because it's a little off axis because of the image

Comment: @idontunderstandanything Ok great! Feel free to upvote or mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Yeah, sure thing. If you want to start a chatbox, I'm happy to explain what's going on.

Comment: i already did and they said because I'm new it's not publically shown but it's recorded in the database

Comment: @idontunderstandanything Thank you! It just reflected on the page. If you need to start a chatbox for me to explain things more in-depth. Feel free to do so. I also upvoted your answer as you showed what you tried before coming here.

Comment: yes exactly I was searching how to create a chat box but I don't think I can because I don't have reputation points, could you create one and invite me?

Comment: @idontunderstandanything Unfortunately, you need atleast 20 reputation on StackOverflow to talk in chat rooms. I'm sorry!

Comment: oh i'm already at 13! i'll create one when I have 20. Also i saw you're a software engineer! I'd like to do that path too i'm curious to ask a few questions!

Comment: Yeah I upvoted your questions so you got +10 reputation. Receive one more upvote or answer someones question and you will be over 20! Feel free to email me if you ever need some guidance or want to chat. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display: block` to span tag.

```html
<span style="text-align: center; display: block">cutie</span>
```

Comment: now it is aligned to the center but the text has went down a line even tho it's in the <header> , here is some context 
` <div class="container"> 
<header> 
<img class="cats" src="black.jpeg" alt="beautiful cat"> 
<span class="p2"> cutie</span>
 </header> ` 
and i want it in the same line as the <img>

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly that you want the text centered and to the right of the photo then flexbox can help here. Try this snippet:

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center">
    <img class="cats" src="black.jpg" alt="beautiful cat">
    <span style="text-align: center; padding-left: 20px;">cutie</span>
</div>
```

If you are wanting the text below the picture I suggest using `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`:

```
<figure>
  <img class="cats" src="black.jpg" alt="beautiful cat">
    <figcaption style="text-align: center;">cutie</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: sorry i meant aligned to the center of the page and the image at the left like it is by default all in the same line